# Finding a C# dictionary using a string

Tags: c#, dictionary

I'd like to find a dictionary by using a string in order to copy it into a new dictionary -- seems like it should be simple but I'm not sure of syntax.

Basically it's just:

```
    // the object's myName corresponds to an existing dictionary
    string stringdic = myName;      

    // here's where I try to create a new dictionary containing the values of the existing dictionary
    Dictionary<string, int> mySkills = new Dictionary<string, int>(myName);
```

The goal here is just to create an object with a given string as its "name", and from the name know which out of a set of dictionaries it should use -- for example if myName = Bob, I want to access the dictionary Bob in this script.

Thus some other way of referencing the pre-existing dictionary to get its keys / values would also work. Speed is not a big issue, but I'd like to keep the code simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how you do a Dictionary of Dictionaries:

```
var persons = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>
{
    { "Jeremy", new Dictionary<string, int> { { "age", 20 }, { "height_cm", 180 } } },
    { "Evan", new Dictionary<string, int> { { "age", 18 }, { "height_cm", 167 } } },
};

Dictionary<string, int> x = persons["Jeremy"];
x["age"] = 34;
```

Comment: Thanks, that's perfect for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to be able to lookup a dictionary using a string, you can have a dictionary of dictionaries, something like:

```
using X = Dictionary<string, int>;

var all = new Dictionary<string, X>();

X mySkills = all[myName];
```